# Why does google app engine seem to use old code?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, adonis.js

I've setup Google App Engine to run my AdonisJS API for my website. I update the code using the CLI for google cloud services ("gcloud app deploy"). I get a success message from the terminal, and I have checked both the cloud build and version number, and both are the most recent deployment. However, when I try to use my website, I get an error due to the API using old code and trying to access table columns from my database that no longer exist. I have downloaded the most recent cloud build file and checked the codebase within it and the updated code is there. I have also tried deploying multiple times, and it still is using the old code. Does anyone know why this is happening and/or how to fix this?

If you need more information, let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER:
Fixed this a while ago, but wanted to update here just in case others ran into this. I discovered that when deploying to GAE through the command line, my build command wasn't running prior to the deploy since my script had an error, so it was uploading updated code, but not an updated build. So just make sure to run the build command prior to uploading to GAE and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. In console.cloud.google.com, go to your GAE project and check which version of your project is running I.e. which one is receiving traffic
2. Clear your cache.